# Convert Zip to byte array Vb 2015

Tags: arrays, vb.net, zip

I managed to zip the files dynamically in my vb program. Now I need to retrieve the zip file byte by byte so that I can split the byte into two 4 bits and embed it to the last 4 bits of pixel of an image.

How can I access the zip file byte by byte. or How can I convert the zip file to a byte array.

I will be using vb 2015.

Comment: You should include any research and any code that is relevant to this question. Please see [ask].

Comment: I googled for some sample code for converting to byte array, I could not find any. I'm new to vb

Comment: Perhaps `File.ReadAllBytes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thanks guys for helping.
The code I used is added here

```
    Dim Mystream As New FileStream("C:\STEG\result.zip", FileMode.Open)
    Dim filesize As Long = Mystream.Length
    Dim buffer(filesize) As Byte
    Mystream.Read(buffer, 0, filesize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting a file to byte array would be a complete overkill depending on how big it is and what you pretend to do with those bytes.

> How can I access the zip file byte by byte.

You can use the **[FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx)** Class:

```
Using fs As New FileStream("C:\Archive.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read)
    ' ...
End Using
```

Notice the `Read`, `ReadByte`, `Write`, `WriteByte`, `Seek` and `Position` members of the class. See MSDN for documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your reference to Filestream solved the issue